# Authorization in ASP.NET with Angular through Active Directory

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core, active-directory

I have several SPA implemented using ASP.NET Core. Authorization in them occurs using a form. Most often, these applications are used by users on the intranet. Therefore, there was a question of authorization with Active Directory.

For a long time of searches (about 1.5 - 2 weeks), all I could find is that it is possible. And I was able to get the user name and domain name (using the namespace System).

I ran into such a question repeatedly, but I could not find an answer, code or articles that would help me.

Until this point, I've never interacted with Active Directory. Therefore, I want to ask you for help.

In general, the question is: how to authorize a user in the SPA using Active Directory, without entering a login and password, if it is on the intranet?

- How do I interact with Active Directory from an ASP.NET Core application?
- Ideally, if the user on the intranet, then authorize automatically, otherwise ask for a login and password. In the future, I will strive for this.
- And the question for the future: how to differentiate access rights for different users? Assign roles, etc. Which are currently used in the application. Can this be done using Active Directory tools or do I have to use the application database to match the user and his roles?

I will be very grateful for any article, guidance! And also for some basic project.

Comment: Check Microsoft.AspNet.Identity; namespace. It allows all features of windows identity being provided by AD